# Set specific cpu core for task in GNAT

Tags: multicore, ada, gnat

I'm using Gnat and want to set a specific execution core for one of the tasks. The problem is that I couldn't find any docs on that. Despite the addition of System.Multiprocessor, as mentioned [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Implementation-of-Ada-2012-Features.html) and [here](http://www.disca.upv.es/jorge/ae2010/slides/01-3_Multicores_Saez-Crespo_Preliminary_Multiprocessor_Support_Linux.pdf), the compiler keeps saying that it's not a predefined library unit. This happens even if I add the `-gnat12` flag. Any suggestions on how can I use that feature?`

Answer (score 2):

Gnat provides the compiler-specific [Task_Info pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Task_005fInfo.html#Pragma-Task_005fInfo), which associates a Task_Info_Type block of data with a given task. Among the fields of that data block is one used to set processor infinity. The exact definition of the System.Task_Info.Task_Info_Type differs by platform, so you need to review the System.Taskinfo package for the platform on which your executable is running.

(Obviously this is not a portable solution, that is coming with Ada 2012.)

Shameless plug: See the [Magpie](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magpie-mc/) framework hosted at SourceForge for distributing work amongst multicore CPUs for an example of setting processor affinities.

Comment: I believe I have code that does it in the SETI@Home Service (http://www.telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/SETI/SETI_Service.html ) as well. However, it uses Windows OS calls, and does it on a process (not task) basis.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait until your compiler supports the package.

Comment: Correct. Ada 2012 will probably not be available in 2011 ;)

Comment: @NWS - Why not? The 2012 car models are out now. :)

Comment: There is a phrase which could be found in the first mention, that this features have been implemented. So there must be some kind of magic enabling it.

Comment: If you're a supported customer with access to the latest versions of GNAT, you likely then have access to these new features. If you're using GNAT GPL, or FSF GNAT, then not so much...yet :-)

Comment: @TED, Can you supply me with the 2012 horse racing results also ? ;)